# In the many-worlds interpetation, does quantum revival imply that the universe will repeat itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, poincare-recurrence

[Quantum revival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_revival) is the idea that unitary evolution of the wavefunction implies that evolution of the wavefunction is periodic. Since the many-worlds interpretation stipulates that there is only unitary evolution, then doesn't that imply that all of the worlds will eventually repeat according to the "quantum Poincaré recurrence theorem"?

Comment: The Wikipedia article that you linked has few edits, and most of them are by a single user. I think it's received little to no editorial "peer review" on Wikipedia.

Comment: @benrg, if you have an alternative suggestion for a link on quantum revival, that is also fine -- but it's my opinion that its a fairly well-known concept so the link isn't even particularly necessary.